# C++ Invalid Comparator sorting Vector of Structs

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, struct

I'm trying to Sort a `std::vector` containing custom structures, each of which has its own `vector` of `int` values.  The key is that I want to sort based on the ordering of the internal `int` `vector`... i.e. `{1, 1, 2, 3, 4}` is less than `{1, 2, 2, 3, 4}` because of the second value in the `vector`.

It seems to me that this would provide a strict weak ordering but I always receive an Invalid Comparator exception when running it.  I've also tried to implement a separate key function as the third parameter for `std::sort()` but the same thing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

typedef struct AA {
    std::vector<int> AA_v;
    bool operator<(const AA& a1)const {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->AA_v.size(); i++) {
            if (this->AA_v[i] < a1.AA_v[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}AA;

void main(void) {
    AA a1, a2, a3, a4;
    a1.AA_v = { 1, 1, 3, 5, 4 };
    a2.AA_v = { 1, 1, 2, 4, 5 };
    a3.AA_v = { 0, 1, 3, 5, 4 };
    a4.AA_v = { 1, 1, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::vector<AA> AA_vector;
    AA_vector.push_back(a1);
    AA_vector.push_back(a2);
    AA_vector.push_back(a3);
    AA_vector.push_back(a4);

    std::sort(AA_vector.begin(), AA_vector.end());
}
```

Comment: Must be `int main`, not `void main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
bool operator<(const AA& a1)const {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->AA_v.size(); i++) {
        if (this->AA_v[i] < a1.AA_v[i]) {
            return true;
        } 
        else if (this->AA_v[i] > a1.AA_v[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

otherwise, with your code, `{3, 1}` result lesser than `{1, 3}` and result also true that `{1, 3}` is lesser than `{3, 1}`.

P.s.: but you can also use the `operator<()` for vectors

```
bool operator< (const AA& a1) const
 { return this->AA_v < a1.AA_v; }
```

Comment: I didn't realize you would need to force the other false and I'm surprised I hadn't come across the the operator<() for vectors.